# Maven cannot find opencsv csv parser

Tags: java, maven, csv

I've come across one problem with maven and opencsv

I am trying to use the csvparser as followed:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class FlightsByCarrierMapper extends
                Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        if (key.get() > 0) {
            String[] lines = new
        CSVParser().parseLine(value.toString());
            context.write(new Text(lines[8]), new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the opencsv dependency and can use the csvreader without problem. The csvparser though cannot be resolved and throws and error whenever I try to compile the code.

Maven then throws the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project FlightsByCarrier: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /root/workspace/FlightsByCarrier/src/main/java/com/root/hadoop/FlightsByCarrier/FlightsByCarrierMapper.java:[6,30] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package au.com.bytecode.opencsv
[ERROR] /root/workspace/FlightsByCarrier/src/main/java/com/root/hadoop/FlightsByCarrier/FlightsByCarrierMapper.java:[18,2] error: cannot find symbol
```

The dependency looks like this right now:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems the class `CSVParser` does not exist in [opencsv 1.8](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/1.8/). This class was introduced in [opencsv 2.1](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/2.1/).

As such, you need to update your dependency to version 2.1 at least.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Note that starting with the 3.x branch, the artifact was relocated to the [`com.opencsv:opencsv`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv/3.7) coordinate. It would be better to use the latest version of the library:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

You will need to update your imports also to `import com.opencsv`.

Comment: When I add the last dependency to my pom.xml file.. CSVReader nor CSVParser doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Nique Oh that's weird. I just retested by adding that dependency and I have `com.opencsv.CSVParser` and `com.opencsv.CSVReader` classes. Are you sure the download wasn't corrupted?

Comment: I tried a couple of times. Removing and adding. Its in the external Libraries list in Intellij. see http://i.imgur.com/MkklDqs.png

Comment: When I remove the above dependency the unfolded library on the left gets removed. I couldn't find a CSVReader in it. Is it importing the wrong library? This is so weird.

Comment: @Nique Hmm I don't see any `com.opencsv` dependency in your screenshot. Are you sure you added that dependency in the `<build><dependencies>` section of your POM?

Comment: I just found out what the problem is. Don't add the <bundle> tag in dependency. Even while the docs say it: (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/dependency-info.html)

Comment: @Nique Ha! Yes, apparently the doc has an issue here. I don't have this `<type>` in my answer.